# Navigation drawer - disable swipe

Tags: android

Is there any way to disable swipe gesture to open navigation drawer? Its really annoying when menu appears while swiping between tabs.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You can use

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

to lock your `DrawerLayout` so it won't be able to open with gestures. And unlock it with:

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);`

Here you can find more info about `DrawerLayout`: [Android API - DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks! It's work, also You can use DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN for set panel opened.

Comment: Currently there is a bug with the method. I have reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738274