# Disable Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a **Navigation Drawer** successfully using the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and some tutorials. This works perfectly fine.

Now, I have added an **In-App-Purchase** to unlock the full functionality of my app. This extra functionality is accessed through the Navigation Drawer. I have a boolean which gets a `true` or `false` value in the `onCreate()` of the Activity based on if the user has or not made this purchase.

So far so good.

Now, I wan't to **lock** the Navigation Drawer if the boolean is `false`. What is a good/correct way to do this? Do I need to add `if-else` blocks at all the child fragments where the Drawer is being toggled or affected? Is there any *universal lock* which I can conveniently use?

**Update:** I tried using `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` in my `Activity.onCreate()` after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901504/navigation-drawer-disable-swipe) question, but it **does not work**.

Comment: I did see that question, however the function does not seem to be work. Updating the question now.

Comment: you can try making a custom drawer as I described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26730570/2389078) answer. That way you can manage the button clicks, until the variable is not true, because you'll only be opening the drawer by your wish. I think you get my point.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Do Like This.

```
// enable or disable slide menu
public void setDrawerLayoutEnable(boolean what) {
    if (what) {
        // Drawer will be open through swipe by user
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    } else {
        // User will not be able to open Drawer but it can be open from application programmatically 
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }
}
```

This might helps you.

Comment: where would I call this method? I tried to call this in onCreate() of my Activity and it does not help.

Comment: u don;t need to call it anywhere it just works on the object of DrawerLayout.

Comment: `setDrawerLayoutEnable` is not a standard method. I will have to invoke it somewhere. What do you mean by 'it just works on the object of DrawerLayout'?

Comment: yes it's not override method.

Comment: so I'm asking where should I invoke it? As I say in my question, I already tried calling the `setDrawerLockMode` in my `onCreate()` and it did not work.

Comment: you need to call this method where you wanted to precent user to open drawer @rgamber

Comment: sorry, I am not following you.

Comment: have you created custom actionbar for navigation??

Comment: @SilentKiller, I mentioned in the question that I am calling this on my onCreate, but its not working.

Comment: @rgamber where at on create ?

Comment: at the very end, after initializing the drawer completely. Its not working!