# android - how to pass touch move event ViewPager that has ListView in Drawer?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, drawer

There is ViewPager that has some fragments.
That fragments have the listView.

And the ViewPager is in the Drawer.

so, I want to move ViewPager left fragment or right fragment, but the drawer is moved.

listView in fragment is preventing the touch event.

How can I move ViewPager without moving Drawer?

Comment: Try this link - [Navigation drawer - disable swipe ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901504/navigation-drawer-disable-swipe)

Comment: omg! thank you! it work!

Comment: Have Fun and please upvote